# Rails 3 Named Routes - Calling different actions in the controller dynamically as a parameter with the same named route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, custom-routes

Say i have a controller with index and doesn't have any other RESTful actions. I want to call different actions as a parametr from the same controller which has a named route as follows.

Example,

I have TargetsController and i should be able to call

```
targets_path(any_action, params)
```

Can i call

```
resources :targets do 
  get :action_name, :on => :member 
end
```

on a controller that does not have the Restful actions

How do i write this in the routes.rb ? All the documentation i found did not talk about how the same route is called in the controller. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing it with url_for helper